# PyCharm can't handle mpl_toolkits

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Am trying to examine a python code in pycharm.  I need the package mpi_toolkits.mplot3d, which -- as I understand it -- is supposed to be a default part of the matplotlib package.  pycharm can load matplotlib.pyplot, but when I try

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
```

I tried replacing the default python interpreter with another interpreter on my system where I know mpl_toolkits is working just fine.  No go.  Same error.

Anyone know how to get mpl_toolkits/mplot3d working in PyCharm?

Comment: Something funky must be going on with your installation of matplotlib, I can use mplot3d and Axes3D just fine in PyCharm

Comment: @DizietAsahi  Thanks.  But I tested that by going to another interpreter where everything is works correctly.

Comment: Are you sure PyCharm and your other interpreter are using the same python installation? You can check the packages installed and available to PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-interpreter.html